# Computer freezes up when running network troubleshooting

Tags: networking, freeze

I've been having some problems with my Dell laptop recently, and unfortunately, the fixes suggested by the people at the Dell forums actually introduced some new issues. For the record, [here's the thread in question](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/network-internet-wireless/f/3324/p/19988423/20934913).

In short, I've been having problems keeping my computer connected to the Internet since I moved and switched to Comcast (I have no idea if the problem was due to the provider, or my new equipment, or what). The connection would drop out at random times, and in order to get back online, I would have to run the Windows troubleshooter and wait for it to resolve my connection issues.

OK, so that was bad enough. But after running some of the suggested fixes, which included updating the BIOS and running a "netsh int ip reset" command through Command Prompt, my computer now completely freezes up anytime I try to run the Wi-fi troubleshooter; in addition, it sometimes freezes up if I try to turn Airplane Mode on, or even reconnect to my network after I've been kicked off. It's so severe that even <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> doesn't work. I have to do a hard reset by holding in the power button.

I'm completely at a loss. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do? I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the network driver; that didn't work, and neither did refreshing Windows.

As a side note, I should note that the sleep issue that I mentioned in the Dell thread doesn't seem to be occurring anymore.

Specs:

```
OS: Windows 10
Model: Inspiron 3543 Signature Edition
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00 GHz 2.00 GHz
```

Comment: If a fresh install of an OS with proper drivers for the network adaptor doesn't work, then I'd suspect it's the hardware. But as is, this is too broad (IMO).

Comment: What can I do to make it more specific?  Are there any tests I can run, etc.?

Comment: Do and add more research.  Did you try it on another network? Have you tried a fresh windows install? Or tried another OS (ie: a Linux Live boot)?  Exactly which driver's were you trying to use? More info = less broad. :)

Comment: I haven't tried it on another network, but my wife's computer works perfectly on the network.  I was under the impression that refreshing Windows reinstalled it; is that incorrect?  The current driver is: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHz).  I tried installing the previous version of the driver, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I'm actually OK with the network connection failing, and needing to manually reconnect and/or run the troubleshooter.  The real problem is with Windows completely freezing up anytime I try to run the troubleshooter or reconnect to the network.

Comment: Try to boot with a different OS (maybe a usb Linux pen drive) and to see if the problem persists. If it disappears completely it means it is a driver/OS problem. If appears again but it will be not continuous it should be related to hardware outside your computer. If you can connect with your computer to other network is not related with your hardware. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer has Dell Wireless 1704 802.11b/g/n.
Compare to your wife's computer working just fine.  See my list below - does your Xfinity named connection appear in Network or a generic one?

I recommend simply purchasing a NetGear USB Wifi adapter.
If your router supports it you can even upgrade from 802.11b/g/n doing this.

Since no built-in WiFi, this was my solution for my Dell Inspiron.
My Dell Inspiron One's NIC adapter by Realtek (ethernet) with latest driver still acted up:
 1. initially connected - (see proper Xfinity named device = good, but "Ethernet device" = not good)
 2. yellow flag appears after 30 seconds - connected but no internet 
 3. Windows 10 troubleshooter started
 4. LOCKED UP PC at Reset step of troubleshooter.